Are curious web programming questions allowed on Stack Overflow (even though it has no practical applications)?
I had a theory concerning the promise returned by fetch, and I wanted to verify if I am correct on the matter or not, since there aren't many good web resources on the topic. However, the response I received was unexpected, to say the least.
Shortly after posting my question Does the fetch API's C++ code resolves the promise when a response is obtained?, seeking to verify a theory I had about how the browser's fetch API resolves promises, I was met with four immediate downvotes followed by a closing vote. The question was swiftly labeled as "not focused," leaving me confused as to why. Wasn't the focus crystal clear? I simply wanted to delve into the mechanics behind an aspect of the JavaScript engine.
Despite my efforts to refine the question and make it more "on-topic" to the community, it remained closed. The frustration mounted as I attempted to understand why my inquiry was deemed unworthy of discussion. I do not know what I did wrong; the closing vote sounds very confusing also.
However, amidst the confusion, a comment caught my attention. It struck a chord with me, but I found such comment to be quite dismissive. The commenter argued that such distinctions were meaningless, asserting that the fetch API is what it is – a tool provided by the browser with a straightforward promise-based interface:

It's a meaningless distinction. Fetch is part of the browser. You call fetch. You get a promise. At some point the promise resolves. That's the API. That's all you need to care about unless you are editing the browser's source code to change how it works (and if you're doing that then "Which bit of $NAMED_OPEN_SOURCE_BROWSERS source code is responsible for resolving the promise returned by fetch?" would be a more reasonable question, but probably still not a very good one as few people would know the answer, and if you have to ask then you probably couldn't make good use of the answer)

While I could appreciate the simplicity of this viewpoint, it also left me feeling somewhat dismissed. Sure, there is probably no beneficial reason for knowing this, but to say the least, Stack Overflow is developed for
this very reason: A Q&A site where users can learn and share programming information.
Does Stack Overflow truly welcome inquiries driven by pure curiosity? If this question does not rightfully belong on Stack Overflow, is there another Stack Exchange community where questions like this are better suited?

"Despite my efforts to refine the question and make it more "on-topic" to the community, it remained closed. " When you made those edits you never stated that they fixed the question by ticking the box to send it to the review queue, so it's not that surprising it remained closed; you never requested people to review it to get it opened.

there's probably a good question in there somewhere, but it's hidden it what looks to me like a lot of confusion about concepts in promises/async, which I don't think helps spark interest of experts. note: generally, questions here should be "practical" (for some definition of that word). see /help/dont-ask. note that few people knowing the answer does not make a question poorer (I disagree with the commenter you quote on that).

If you did check the box and then go to the post history, you'll see something like "submitted for review". Next time please make sure that your post is submitted for review if you meant for it. Also, if I remember correctly, that box is checked by default for you unless you explicitly uncheck it yourself.

@Weijun Zhou, I do not know. I am using a screen-reading software for most of my activity on Stack Overflow. Maybe Stack Overflow isn't accessible to screen readers? Anyway, thank you for the comment.

Stack Overflow is accessible to screen readers, but I'm not sure about how well it performs in this particular aspect.

@Weijun Zhou, I think you are absolutely right; I haven't really experienced any navigation-related problems on Stack Overflow. If you say that the review-queue checkbox is checked by default, then my edited-question should have gone into the queue, because I did not uncheck the box on purpose.

@jonrsharpe The titles of both questions are basically the same, but they're asking different things. The suggested target is asking about very focused questions that have no (obvious) practical use. This question is asking about relatively open-ended questions (that also have no obvious practical use). I don't think that duplicate applies here.

Question asked from false premises are difficult to answer and often downvoted. Your question starts by calling fetch synchronous, when it's actually asynchronous. You might want to take a few steps back and re-examine the fundamental premises to make sure they're sound. Similarly, if you asked "why does 2 + 3 equal 6?", the question is unanswerable, uninteresting and unuseful, because it begins with the false premise that 2 + 3 = 6. It doesn't apply to mathematical reality in any meaningful way.

@ggorlen, Thanks for your comment. I completely disagree with what you are saying. You say my question is based off a false primase. I am simply saying that the fetch is just a method on the window object, which is pushed unto the stack and returns a promise immediately (the browser handles the sending of web requests).

@ggorlen, Perhaps this question may explain why I have this "misconception" you seem to pointing out in your comment. If the setTimeout function hands off its job to the browser and immediately returns, what is different than about fetch (they are both browser APIs).

@ggorlen, to make my point more clear, the asynchronous events (like HTTP requests) are handled within the browser's internal C++ implementation, not in the JS engine. The fetch function is just an intermediary between the web API and the JS engine: It provides the JavaScript developers with a mean to access the browser feature. So, why is that synchronous? I believe that the asynchronous requests are soly the browser's job; the fetch is just a "middleman" for it.

@NapoleonBonaparte perhaps this wonderful article that I just found will answer your questions.

@NapoleonBonaparte fetch is an asynchronous function because it returns a promise. setTimeout provides a callback that runs asynchronously. If you consider fetch as synchronous, then there are no asynchronous functions in JS. It's as async as you can get! What the browser does is irrelevant; I'm talking strictly about JS terminology--async and sync funcs. I think you're just arguing terminology at this point. The point in my comment holds: you're coming into the post with a fundamentally different (and inaccurate) understanding of the world such that the question makes no sense to me.

@ggorlen, Can you then agree on this fact: that fetch immediately returns a pending promise and hands the job to the other threads in the borwser for processing?

@NapoleonBonaparte No, I don't agree to all of that. Those are implementation details that may or may not be true for all engines. It's not necessarily true that async involves threads--and even if it does or doesn't, I don't see how it matters. All I agree to is that fetch is an asynchronous function, and all async functions return promises. If you define a synchronous function as something that returns a promise, then the term "asynchronous function" has no meaning.

@ggorlen, "all async functions return promises" - no, MutationObserver, setTimeout, and setImmediate are some JS async functions that do not return a promise.

@NapoleonBonaparte Those aren't async (the keyword) functions. Those functions accept callbacks that are triggered asynchronously. But sure, call them async if you want. It doesn't matter--feel free to define async funtions as "functions that return a promise or accept an asynchronously-triggered callback". I hope this exercise makes the downvotes on your post obvious--you're arguing a bunch of random pedantic points unconstructively, from false premises, without any obvious purpose or objective. What practical problem are you actually trying to solve?

@ggorlen, I actually don't mind the downvotes. I cannot understand why the community has shown so much abhorrence for this particular question. I'm just asking a question. If I don't ask, I'll never understand. So, I don't regret asking.

And yet, have I followed all of SO's guidelines for writing a question that is clear? I have explained my problem, tried my best to use proper English grammar, and it is still "not good enough". If I can find an answer that is of good quality and correct, why would I waste my time here writing a question that will just be downvoted anyway?

@NapoleonBonaparte It's not "a practical, answerable problem"--it's a speculation about unspecified browser internals based on unclear or false premises. A question needs more than being broadly about programming and good English to be practical and answerable. Your question is probably also subject to the meta effect, which will compound the "abhorrence"--pushback and insisting that it's a good question probably also doesn't help, though I'm not sure of the deletion timeline.

I have to preface this with none of what you are asking matters. This is extremely important. I will front-load the information here, your question is

What resolves the promise in a browser fetch API?
Is it the browser or the fetch?

(The last line from an earlier revision but relevant to address)

Does not matter in any practical way.
Different browser implementations could do either. As in fetch can off-load to another API and just serve to bridge the promise. Or the implementation could be in fetch.
With that said: both fetch and whatever fetch calls (if any) should just be considered "the browser". So, in a way the answer is simply "yes". And that is absolutely impractical. See 1.


With that out of the way, the question has a whole slew of problems with understanding what actually goes on. It would be much better to focus on individual points or research to ask what you really want to ask. Because there is a lot of misconceptions there:

The fetch function in JavaScript is synchronous--it gets added to the call stack and popped off once it finishes its execution.


No, it is not synchronous. It is very (in)famously asynchronous. The majority of questions about fetch we get are usually variations of not understanding it is async.
It absolutely does not work as described, either.


The browser is what makes the GET request. It will return a promise immediately.

The last sentence is correct. It is also in conflict with claiming fetch is synchronous.

Say the fetching process takes 2 seconds to complete. By the end of two seconds, the fetch will be popped off the call stack.

Not at all how asynchronous calls work. Again, in conflict with the earlier "It will return a promise immediately."

Therefore, it wouldn't make sense to think that the fetch resolved the promise.

It would "make sense" but also does not matter. Promises can wrap other promises and assume their state. Who resolves a promise is completely irrelevant. It is not at all useful to consider it because this can be an implementation detail that changes, and you have zero influence over it. Nor does your code have any dependency on this. Consider the library code
/* public member */
function a() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve(true));
}

now consider another library. Maybe a newer verion of the above:
/* public member */
function a() {
    return b();
}

/* private member */
function b() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve(true));
}

and a third option:
/* public member */
function a() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve(b()));
}

/* private member */
function b() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve(true));
}

in all cases consuming code would just call a. Where exactly is the promise really resolved has no impact on the consumer.

The only possible option that will trigger the resolution of the pending promise is the browser itself.
Is that correct?

Well, yes. It is also not a useful information. Because, again, fetch is not some sort of non-browser thing1.
If we remove the fluff talk about promises, callstacks, and sync/async essentially the question boils down to "Is the Fetch API provided by the browser?". For which we essentially have a duplicate already (the title just tackles it from the other side): Is the Fetch API an ECMAscript feature?
Note that the duplicate does not focus on irrelevant details like "who resolves the promise". It is the much more practical implication of "where is fetch specified" which can help in the future if you need to find the specification or need to perhaps try to figure out if some behaviour with fetch is down to the spec standard2.
But perhaps you are wondering whether there really is a difference? Is the "who resolves a promise" not practical or not answerable? I would argue that in addition to the question as asked being not useful, there are several issues:

Several at the very least odd, if not outright wrong misconceptions about fundamental things before even starting to answer how a particular promise is resolved.
With those aside, the question is tantamount to asking "For all possible browsers and probably different versions of browsers, how is an internal call, one irrelevant to consumers, handled?"
The answer(s) would be something like:


In Firefox n fetch calls __internal_fetch();
In Firefox n+1 this was changed and the code is inlined in fetch;
In Firefox n+m now fetch calls __other_internal_fetch();
In Chrome n [...]"




Which, I would reiterate again, is not a very useful information. Not to mention annoying to get ahold of and update consistently with more browser releases (and newer version of existing browsers).
ALSO, I should note that the title "Does the fetch API's C++ code resolves the promise when a response is obtained?" does not match the body. The body talks about various JavaScript mechanisms of asynchronicity. The title asks about something that is not in the body. I suppose in part the title might be answered by Why does .json() return a promise, but not when it passes through .then()? but it is hard to say. There might be a question in the title worth answering. But there is no follow up on it, nor clarity what the title actually means.

1 When we are talking about browsers. There is the Fetch API in Node but that is not what the questions asks about. Nor is it much different if you just replace "browser" with "environment".
2 For example, if you transpile your code and set your target level to ECMAScript 2016 vs ECMAScript 2020 and wonder if that has an effect on the Fetch API usage. It does not because it is not affected by the ECMAScript spec version.

Thanks for your answer. I thought that the fetch function will return a promise when it is invoked. The reason I thought the fetch was synchronous is because I remember reading somewhere claiming that the browser is what handles the GET request, the only thing that fetch do is hand off the request to the browser and return a pending promise, which will be resolved later when the browser obtains a result. If my understanding on this matter is not correct, are you suggesting that the fetch does not get pushed unto the stack? Is that true for all browser APIs? Sorry if my question is very basic:)

"I thought that the fetch function will return a promise when it is invoked." it does "return a pending promise, which will be resolved later when the browser obtains a result" that describes asynchronous operations. Promises are notification mechanism for those. There is little sense for a synchronous operation to return a promise. In fact, if there is a synchronous operation which still produces a promise,  that's exceptionally likely to be a mistake. "are you suggesting that the fetch does not get pushed unto the stack?" I didn't suggest that and I don't know why you ask.

It's becoming very clear you have some mental model of what's happening but you've not explained what it is. You seem to be trying to adjust it but without revealing what the mental model is. What stack? The question and the body (and now this comment) have a disjointed talk about some stack but I don't know where you think the stack fits in. Or why. All the stack talk seems to just be wrong but without a clear reason what is wrong there.

I'd suggest you step back, you re-examine your assumptions, maybe check some resources, and then probably re-ask as better question focusing on some more actionable information. Right now you're trying ask questions with multiple unknowns making it hard to answer. And having some sort of answer, you've not added another unknown. This question isn't basic, it just lacks clarity about how exactly should it be answered. Meta isn't the place for this anyway.

"I thought that the fetch function will return a promise when it is invoked. The reason I thought the fetch was synchronous is because I remember reading somewhere claiming that the browser is what handles the GET request" - in your own words, exactly what do you think a promise is, in this context?

@Karl Knechtel, I believe the promise represented here is a container for the eventual response of a web request. Of course, I do not believe that the promise is the thing that handles the sending of the request. All I am saying is that they are completely separate - promise, in this case, is being used by fetch to communicate the response back to the developer; fetch is just an intermediary for the job. What other purpose does fetch have beside signaling the browser that there is a fetch request? Why wouldn't the fetch function just return immediately and let the web APIs do the job?

"I believe the promise represented here is a container for the eventual response of a web request" Right. And the container can be, and is, returned immediately. But it doesn't have any content until the response is actually received. Which can't possibly happen synchronously, because you'd be holding up the entire program execution for an amount of time that couldn't possibly be known in advance (you are at the mercy of the other server, and the Internet connection). Thus, you get the promise object synchronously, but evaluate it asynchronously.

@Karl Knechtel, that is what I have been trying to communicate. I have never said that the process of fetching a piece of web resource is synchronous. I am saying that the fetch function is synchronous: it just hands off the job to the browser API and immediately returns a pending promise. Is that not right?

@Karl Knechtel, Thus, my question is naturally formed: what resolves the promise returned by fetch? I now understand that such question has too many possible answers, and it is not in a scope where it can be answered with several paragraphs. Thanks for your comment.

@Karl Knechtel, since calling fetch() creates a new execution context, surely it will be placed unto the call stack. If fetch never pop off the call stack, how will the event loop then handle microtasks and continue with other code which is written to be executed in the same current task? This is why I say fetch() is synchronous.

I have no clue why you keep going on about call stacks and fetch being synchronous. Every single async function will start being on the call stack then return a promise. Simplest example is async () => { const r = await f(); return r; }. For all practical reasons a "synchronous-promise-producing function" is called asynchronous. Because there is no sense in differentiating them. Because there it doesn't matter to the consumer. It's like trying to distinguish whether something is "soup" or "liquid food" yet the only thing you would do with or without this information is eat it with a spoon.


Does Stack Overflow truly welcome inquiries driven by pure curiosity?

The honest answer is: No.
Curiosity motivates wonderful questions that allow for long and winding walks amidst the pillars of opinion, boasting in-depth knowledge and irrelevant facts for real life use.
That type of question might work on Discussions - the part of Stack Overflow where the standards applicable to Q&A don't apply, which is set to become as famous as Yahoo! Answers.
On Stack Overflow, questions need to be about practical software engineering issues - which might include or be applicable to a bit of code - that can be answered in a few paragraphs.
Curious questions sometimes evolve around a misunderstanding about, or misinterpretation of, core concepts. For future visitors to value such a question, they would need to have followed the same thought process to reach the same point. It would be pure luck if that happened. Subject Matter Experts (SMEs) need to determine whether there is an actual question to be answered, and if so, how much lack of knowledge they need to cover first to bridge the gap between your question and addressing the practical underlying issue. They run the risk of explaining too much ("I already know that!") or too little ("How did you go from Foo to Bar?"). This tends to result in Chameleon questions - so called because they keep changing.
Looking at your actual question, there are a few indications that you're missing some key understanding about how promises work in JavaScript. I would not use the term "call stack" when talking about promises and how their awaitable results are handled. I would expect terms like "event loop" and "queues". You might know this, or not, I can't tell. Maybe the call stack is important to you (since your title says something about a C++ API) but then I don't comprehend the body of the question. But I'm not a JS-engine SME.
Perhaps you've looked at the Node JS engine or V8 and are trying to understand things within that limited scope; but in this case your curiousity is getting ahead of your ability to explain exactly what you're asking about.
Even after the edit, your question lacks context that is needed to understand for others why you're asking it in the first place. Once that is clear we might have a question that is valuable for future visitors to find and for SMEs to answer.

Indeed, the site tour even has a section that says "Get answers to practical, detailed questions", within which it states: "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced." (emphasis theirs). In other words, if you aren't actually having a problem about the thing your question is about, don't ask it on SO.

@rene, thanks for your answer. You say I shouldn't use the word "call stack". But that is how some of promise code are executed (for example, the callback passed to the Promise constructor). I do understand that some part of promise code are executed asynchronously, like the callback passed to then, catch, etc. I also do not understand why you say my question lacks context. I believe that my reason for asking the question is clearly stated in the body of my question.

@NapoleonBonaparte "But that is how some of promise code are executed (for example, the callback passed to the Promise constructor)" this is completely irrelevant. Yes, the body of the promise constructor callback is executed synchronously. However, the use-case for the constructor is to convert already async but non-promise code (usually callbacks) to a promise. In which case, it doesn't matter if the executor is sync. The resolution is async. Usually, the constructor is not used.

"I would expect terms like "event loop" and "queues". You might know this, or not, I can't tell." - yeah this. I find it very hard to discuss such topics in the context of Javascript because there are just so many ways a discussion can completely derail due to a mismatch in understanding of the ecosystem. Practically almost everything in javascript is synchronous because it is a single execution environment. Of course the engine itself might doing things asynchronously behind the scenes, but from the perspective of the application code - its an event loop. Except there are also web workers.
